# Finding Solutions to Trigonometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry

Find all $x$ in the interval (0, $\frac{\pi}{2}$) such that $$\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sin x} + \frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\cos x} = 4\sqrt{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it in the form
$$2\sqrt2\left(\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}\cos x+\frac{\sqrt3+1}{2\sqrt2}\sin x\right)=2\sqrt2\sin 2x.$$
For $\phi=\arcsin\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}$ it implies
$$\sin(x+\phi)=\sin 2x,$$
i.e. $x+\phi=2x+2\pi n$ or $x+\phi=\pi-2x+2\pi n$, $n\in\Bbb Z$. Therefore, the only solutions in $(0,\pi/2)$ are $\phi$ and $\frac{\pi-\phi}{3}$.

Comment: I'm sorry... I really don't understand your solution at all.  Can you elaborate each step?

Comment: 1) Multiplicate both sides by $\sin x\cos x$; 2) using the formula $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$; 3) using the fact that $(\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2})^2+(\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2})^2=1$ to find $\phi$ such that $\sin\phi=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}$ and $\cos\phi=\frac{\sqrt3+1}{2\sqrt2}$; 4) using formula $\sin x\cos\phi+\cos x\sin\phi=\sin(x+\phi)$; 5) dividing both sides by $2\sqrt 2$; 6) using that $\sin x=\sin y$ iff $x=y+2\pi n$ or $x=\pi-y+2\pi n$ ($n\in\Bbb Z$).